# Facebook Authentication from PHP-SDK to Python

Tags: php, python, facebook, google-app-engine, authentication

I'm "translating" a simple app I made with PHP to Python in order to use it in Google App Engine.
In PHP I have the session check and the redirection with this code:

```
$fbuser = null;
$fb = null;

//Start Facebook
$fb = new Facebook(array(
                        'appId'  => $appId,
                        'secret' => $secret,
                        'cookie' => true,));
$session = $fb->getSession();

if ($session) {  
    try {  
        $fbuser = $fb->api('/me');  
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }  
}
if (!$fbuser) {
    $loginUrl = $fb->getLoginUrl(array('canvas' => 1, 'fbconnect' => 0,
                                             'req_perms' => 'publish_stream, offline_access, user_birthday, user_location, email',
                                             'next' => $baseUrl,
                                             'cancel_url' => $baseUrl ));

        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\ntop.location.href = \"$loginUrl\";\n</script>";
        exit;
}
```

I've seen the Python-SDK for Facebook but it's very poor and hasn't all the useful method as PHP-SDK!
Can you help me translate this code to Python?

Comment: What have you got so far?  This isn't rentacoder, and this question sounds more like "write my code for me" then "help me write it".

Comment: absolutely not! since a lot of people have been developing facebook applications using python I thought that code for sort this out was already available. Calm down, we are here to learn and share not to accuse or exploit other's work.

Comment: I would also like to know the solution to this problem.

Comment: FYI PHP is now supported on GAE: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/introduction

Answer (score 0):

I think [this example](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/appengine/example.py) from the SDK git repository will give you a hint.

Comment: I've seen it and also tested locally but this is not what I meant. This example is more similar to Facebook Connect rather than to application's authentication e permission request. I hope to be clear.

Comment: I just started an Issue on github: https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/issues/57